# error using std::function (class without member "notify")

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I want to notify to another class that a variable was changed, so that I using a callback called notify. I'm a beginner in c++ language and was seeking for the best way to do this and I decided to do it with std::function. But it shows an error, because the callback class is in another file and I can't access to the notify function.

> 77    IntelliSense: class "std::function" has
>   no member "notifyMsg" (...) ClientTs.cpp

ClientTS.cpp

```
cbClientTsFrm callbckFrmGUI;

void registercb(cbClientTsFrm fn){
    callbckFrmGUI = fn;
}
....
// in another function:
callbckFrmGUI.notifyMsg(msgC);
```

ClientTS.h

```
class ClientTsFrm; 
typedef std::function<void(const ClientTsFrm&)> cbClientTsFrm;
```

ClientTSFrm.h

```
class ClientTsFrm : public wxFrame
{
    public:

        explicit  ClientTsFrm(LoginWarnings *warn, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id = 1, const wxString &title = wxT("TeamTranslate"),
                    const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, 
                    long style = wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxRESIZE_BORDER);
(....)
        void notifyMsg(MessagePTR msg);
};
```

I've tried to use Template, but it doesn't work. Please, aside my trouble, any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: An `std::function` is called using regular function call syntax: `callbckFrmGUI();`

Comment: @molbdnilo I used this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2298291/2976034

And I want to send the object in order to that object is notified. So I send "this".

Comment: And that example uses that syntax: `return healthFunc(*this);`

Comment: why should `std::function` have method called `notifyMsg`?

Comment: Yep, it was a misunderstanding. I thought this was a way to do the Observer pattern, but it isn't! Thanks you all.