# How std::bind works with member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdbind

I'm working with `std::bind` but I still don't get how it works when we use it with member class functions.

If we have the following function:

```
double my_divide (double x, double y) {return x/y;}
```

I understand perfectly well the next lines of code:

```
auto fn_half = std::bind (my_divide,_1,2);               // returns x/2

std::cout << fn_half(10) << '\n';                        // 5
```

But now, with the following code where we have a bind to member function I have some questions.

```
struct Foo {
    void print_sum(int n1, int n2)
    {
        std::cout << n1+n2 << '\n';
    }
    int data = 10;
};

Foo foo;

auto f = std::bind(&Foo::print_sum, &foo, 95, _1);
f(5);
```

- Why is the first argument a reference? I'd like to get a theoretical explanation.
- The second argument is a reference to the object and it's for me the most complicated part to understand. I think it's because `std::bind` needs a context, am I right? Is always like this? Has `std::bind` some sort of implementation to require a reference when the first argument is a member function?

Comment: A `&` followed by an identifier does not mean "reference". Not unless it's declaring a variable, in which case the `&` will be preceded by a typename. When `&` is applied to an identifier, you get a *pointer*.

Comment: In general, avoid using `std::bind`.  It has some really deep quirks that make it produce surprising results even after you master the basics.  I find it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

When you say "the first argument is a reference" you surely meant to say "the first argument is a *pointer*": the `&` operator takes the address of an object, yielding a pointer.

Before answering this question, let's briefly step back and look at your first use of `std::bind()` when you use

```
std::bind(my_divide, 2, 2)
```

you provide a function. When a function is passed anywhere it decays into a pointer. The above expression is equivalent to this one, explicitly taking the address

```
std::bind(&my_divide, 2, 2)
```

The first argument to `std::bind()` is an object identifying how to call a function. In the above case it is a pointer to function with type `double(*)(double, double)`. Any other callable object with a suitable function call operator would do, too.

Since member functions are quite common, `std::bind()` provides support for dealing with pointer to member functions. When you use `&print_sum` you just get a pointer to a member function, i.e., an entity of type `void (Foo::*)(int, int)`. While function names implicitly decay to pointers to functions, i.e., the `&` can be omitted, the same is not true for member functions (or data members, for that matter): to get a pointer to a member function it is necessary to use the `&`.

Note that a pointer to member is specific to a `class` but it can be used with any object that class. That is, it is independent of any particular object. C++ doesn't have a direct way to get a member function directly bound to an object (I think in C# you can obtain functions directly bound to an object by using an object with an applied member name; however, it is 10+ years since I last programmed a bit of C#).

Internally, `std::bind()` detects that a pointer to a member function is passed and most likely turns it into a callable objects, e.g., by use `std::mem_fn()` with its first argument. Since a non-`static` member function needs an object, the first argument to the resolution callable object is either a reference or a [smart] pointer to an object of the appropriate class.

To use a pointer to member function an object is needed. When using a pointer to member with `std::bind()` the second argument to `std::bind()` correspondingly needs to specify when the object is coming from. In your example

```
std::bind(&Foo::print_sum, &foo, 95, _1)
```

the resulting callable object uses `&foo`, i.e., a pointer to `foo` (of type `Foo*`) as the object. `std::bind()` is smart enough to use anything which looks like a pointer, anything convertible to a reference of the appropriate type (like `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`), or a [copy] of an object as the object when the first argument is a pointer to member.

I suspect, you have never seen a pointer to member - otherwise it would be quite clear. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int value;
    void f() { std::cout << "f(" << this->value << ")\n"; }
    void g() { std::cout << "g(" << this->value << ")\n"; }
};

void apply(Foo* foo1, Foo* foo2, void (Foo::*fun)()) {
    (foo1->*fun)();  // call fun on the object foo1
    (foo2->*fun)();  // call fun on the object foo2
}

int main() {
    Foo foo1{1};
    Foo foo2{2};

    apply(&foo1, &foo2, &Foo::f);
    apply(&foo1, &foo2, &Foo::g);
}
```

The function `apply()` simply gets two pointers to `Foo` objects and a pointer to a member function. It calls the member function pointed to with each of the objects. This funny `->*` operator is applying a pointer to a member to a pointer to an object. There is also a `.*` operator which applies a pointer to a member to an object (or, as they behave just like objects, a reference to an object). Since a pointer to a member function needs an object, it is necessary to use this operator which asks for an object. Internally, `std::bind()` arranges the same to happen.

When `apply()` is called with the two pointers and `&Foo::f` it behaves exactly the same as if the member `f()` would be called on the respective objects. Likewise when calling `apply()` with the two pointers and `&Foo::g` it behaves exactly the same as if the member `g()` would be called on the respective objects (the semantic behavior is the same but the compiler is likely to have a much harder time inlining functions and typically fails doing so when pointers to members are involved).

Comment: Half way reading this, I was puzzled, who might have wrote such a great explanation? I could've guessed!

Comment: Amazing answer, Dietmar. For me, the keys are: **(1)** While function names implicitly decay to pointers to functions, the same is not true for member functions: to get a pointer to a member function it is necessary to use the &., **(2)** std::bind() detects that a pointer to a member function is passed and most likely turns it into a callable object, and **(3)** To use a pointer to member function an object is needed. When using a pointer to member with std::bind() the second argument to std::bind() correspondingly needs to specify when the object is coming from. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

From [std::bind docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

`bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );` where f is a `Callable`, in your case that  is a pointer to member function. This kind of pointers has some special syntax compared to pointers to usual functions:

```
typedef  void (Foo::*FooMemberPtr)(int, int);

// obtain the pointer to a member function
FooMemberPtr a = &Foo::print_sum; //instead of just a = my_divide

// use it
(foo.*a)(1, 2) //instead of a(1, 2)
```

`std::bind`(and `std::invoke` [in general](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)) covers all these cases in a uniform way. If `f` is a pointer-to-member of `Foo`, then the first `Arg` provided to bind is expected to be an instance of `Foo` (`bind(&Foo::print_sum, foo, ...)` also works, but `foo` is copied) or a *pointer* to `Foo`, like in example you had.

Here is some more reading about [pointers to members](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members), and [1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) gives full information about what bind expects and how it invokes stored function.

You also can use lambdas instead `std::bind`, which could be more clear:

```
auto f = [&](int n) { return foo.print_sum(95, n); }
```

Comment: Oddly enough, `&Foo::print_sum` is *not* a callable! A pointer to member, even a pointer to member function , does _not_ have a function call operator! `std::mem_fn(&Foo::print_sum)` would be a callable. However, `std::bind()` does understand being called with pointer to members as its first argument.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Callable means a little different thing in c++17: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable. And the whole family of `std::mem_fn`, `std::bind` and `std::invoke` just provide a nice interface over base Callable types.

Comment: But this is just a question about terminology.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryPanteleev! I was reading also a very good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c) related with function pointers and pointers to member functions.