# Vector of member functions

Tags: c++

What is the approach to have a vector to schedule method calls of a class. I would like to have a vector of methods, something like this:

```
class Model {
    using task_t = std::function<void()>;
    std::vector<std::vector<task_t>> _frameTasks;

    void add_function() { _frameTasks[3].push_back(&(this->function()); }
    void function() {std::cout << "hi"; }
    void step() {
         for (auto task : _frameTasks[3]) task();
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains that:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.
```

How could I solve this issue or what is the right approach?

Comment: You need to use `std::bind`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions

Comment: A pointer to the function is written `&Model::function`. (But its type is `void(Model::*)()`)

Comment: Use `void add_function() { _frameTasks[3].push_back(std::bind(&Model::function, this)); }`

Comment: Or forget all about `std::bind` and use `push_back( [this](){ function(); } )`.  And usually prefer `for ( auto&& var : range )` to `for ( auto var : range )`.

Comment: @aschepler Oh, that's such a nice solution, thank you!

Comment: @aschepler would it this case the auto&& matter? I wouldn't like to use it without knowing why

Comment: @WooWapDaBug `auto var` always makes a copy of the element, which is usually unnecessary.  `auto&& var` gives you a reference to the element.  (`auto& var` would usually work just as well, but not if the iterator's `operator*` returns a proxy, like for `std::vector<bool>`.)  Here a `std::function` copy might need to do a virtual clone or manipulate a shared use-count or something, but we might as well just skip all that.  (`auto var : range` can be appropriate if for some reason you want to modify a copy of the range element without modifying the original element.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&(this->function())` is applying `&` to the result of the call to the `function()` member function. The default `operator&` requires an lvalue, however, the expression `this->function()` is not an lvalue.

Writing `&Model::function` won't work either because it is a *pointer to a member function* (as opposed to a *pointer to a function*). Its type is `void (Model::*)()`, i.e.: a pointer to a `Model`'s (non-`static`) *member function* that takes no parameters and returns nothing.

You need some way to specify the `Model` *object* on which the `function()` *member function* will be called.

Since C++11 you can achieve that by simply using a *[lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)*:

```
void add_function() {
    _frameTasks[3].push_back(
        [this](){ add_function(); }
    );
}
```

Comment: `&(this->function())` is not a pointer to member function.  It immediately calls the function and attempts to take the address of the returned value (which is not valid if the return type is `void`).  `&Model::function` is the only syntax for a pointer to member function.

Comment: Thanks, it was completely wrong. Either way, I think `&` requires an lvalue, doesn't it? So it can't work even if it is non-`void`.

Comment: Not necessarily. https://wandbox.org/permlink/AFiry9AQUL5AMF7X

Comment: @BaummitAugen Good point. The question would be now: can the `operator&` for `Model` be overloaded outside `Model`'s definition ? If so, OP may as well consider `std::addressof()` instead of `operator&`.

Comment: It sure can. https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q4u9vvLAsH2K9et4 Not for the actual function type though, of course.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Really interesting. Anyway it should be overloaded for `Model::function()`'s return type, not for `Model` itself.

Comment: Yeah, the whole thing about overloaded `operator &` is rather tangential to the discussion at hand to begin with.