# How std::bind(&T::memberFunc, this) can always bind to std::function<void(void)> regardless of what T is?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

As far as I know, the member function pointer only can be assigned to the pointer to member function type, and converted to any other except this will violate the standard, right?

And when calling `std::bind(&T::memberFunc, this)`, it should return a dependent type which depend on `T`.(*in std of VC++ version, it's a class template called `_Binder`*).

So the question becomes to why one `std::funcion` can cover all `_Binder`*(VC++ version)* types.

```
class A
{
public:
    void func(){}
};
class B
{
public:
    void func(){}
};

std::function<void(void)> f[2];

A a;
B b;
f[0] = std::bind(&A::func, &a);
f[1] = std::bind(&B::func, &b);
```

And I can't picture what type of the member of std::funcion which stored the function would be like, unless I am wrong from the first beginning.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions) only covered the member function need to be called with it's instance.

But mine is about why one `std::function` type can hold all `T` types.

Comment: Aren't your bindings equivalent to something like `void f0() { return a.func(); }` and `void f1() { return b.func(); }`?

Comment: No. And `return a.func();`? What's this?@Jean-BaptisteYunès

Comment: @francis, have you seen this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How std::bind works with member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions)

Comment: Yes, but my answer is not there.@SmitYcyken

Comment: Is the question basically "how does type erasure work"?

Comment: @francis, Yes equivalent to `void f0() { a.func(); }`

Comment: I think it's probably an application of **type erasure**. Please leave me an answer.@T.C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the implementation would probably like this:

```
template</*...*/>
class std::bind</*...*/>
{
public:
    std::bind(callable_t call, param_t p)
    {
    _func = [call, p]()/* using lambda to capture all data for future calling */
    {
    p->call();
    };

}
operator std::function<void(void)>()
{

    return _func;

}
private:
std::function<void(void)> _func;
};
```

And **lambda** is the key.

Answer (score 3):

In short what is happening is that `std::bind(&A::func, &a)` returns an object of a class *similar* to

```
class InternalClass
{
    A* a_;  // Will be initialized to &a
public:
    void operator()(void)
    {
        a_->func();
    }
};
```

<sub>[Note that this is highly simplified]</sub>

The callable `operator()` function is what is matches the `void(void)` signature of the `std::function<void(void)>`.

Comment: Still confused. The `InternalClass` is still a dependent type, isn't it? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @francis What does your binding do? Idea is to bind a call to member func on object a (and object b), isn't it? Then what is the signature of a call of member `func`on `a`? A function that takes no parameter and return nothing void f().

Comment: Yes, they are equal things. But, `f0` and `f1` are different things. Then, `std::function` covers both of them magically. i.e. `std::function` covers `InternalClass<A>` and `InternalClass<B>`. That's what I try to understand.@Jean-BaptisteYunès

Comment: @francis `std::function` only cares about the callable function and its signature.

Comment: But `A::func` and `B::func` have different signatures, right?@Someprogrammerdude