# std::bind: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument was not specified

Tags: c++, stdbind

I have the following code:

```
void MyClass::create_msg(MyTime timestamp) {
   // do things here ...
}
```

and I tried to create a std::bind for the above function:

```
MyMsg MyClass::getResult(MyTime timestamp) {
   // do things here ...
   std::bind(create_msg(), timestamp);
   // do things ...
}
```

But got the following error:

```
error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'timestamp' was not specified
    std::bind(create_msg(), timestamp);
              ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
MyClass.cpp:381:1: note: 'create_msg' declared here
void MyClass::create_msg(MyTime timestamp) {
^
1 error generated.
```

What did I do wrong in this case? Thanks!

By the way, same error if I do:

```
std::bind(&MyClass::create_msg(), this, timestamp);
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `bind` over a lambda?

Comment: @pstrjds but it is a member function so it has to be `std::bind(&MyClass::create_msg, this, timestamp)`

Comment: @clcto - You are correct - my bad. I was typing quickly and forgot to take into account that it is a member function.

Comment: In `&MyClass::create_msg()` lose the brackets -> `&MyClass::create_msg`

Comment: Additional worthwhile reading: [How std::bind works with member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues here.

First, the argument you're giving to `std::bind` as your function is currently `create_msg()`. This means "call `create_msg`, take whatever result it produces, and pass that in as the first argument to `std::bind`." That's not what you want - you instead meant "take `create_msg` and pass it as the first parameter to `std::bind`." Since `create_msg` is a member function, you'll need to get a pointer to it like this:

```
std::bind(&MyClass::create_msg, /* ... */)
```

That will address one issue, but there's another one that will then pop up. When you use `std::bind` with a member function pointer, you need to prove `std::bind` with an extra parameter corresponding to the receiver object to use when calling that member function. I believe that in your case you want the current object to be the receiver, which would look like this:

```
std::bind(&MyClass::create_msg, this, timestamp)
```

That should work properly.

However, one could argue that there's a third issue here - rather than using `std::bind`, why not just use a lambda expression?

```
[timestamp, this] { create_msg(timestamp); }
```