# Creating A Template Wrapper for std::bind

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

I am trying to create a simple wrapper function for std::bind, which will take a member function.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void myBindFunction(T &t)
{
   std::bind(T::F, t );
}

MyClass a = MyClass();
myBindFunction <MyClass, &MyClass::m_Function>( a );
```

I'm not sure if what I am trying to achieve it possible?

Comment: Why would you need that? Why using `std::bind` at all, a lambda function would be more appropriate IMO.

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions . Regardless, usually using lambdas is a better and more readable alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the 2nd template parameter a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter), i.e. a member function pointer.

```
template<typename T, void(T::*F)()>
void myBindFunction(T &t)
{
   std::bind(F, t); // bind the member function pointer with the object t
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W78noeOZcfZskUXc)