# No match for call to std::function object which is pointer to member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std-function, member-functions

I want a class to hold a function pointer to a member function of a different class.

But what I get when trying to call that member function using the function pointer, is the error:

> `No match for call to '(const std::function<bool(PropertyCache&)>) ()'`

I don't use raw function pointers but `std::function` objects as this is the way to go if you want to point to member functions (they need the reference to the instance of the class which I call the member function of).

So my first class is the following:

```
class Condition : public ICondition
{
public:

    Condition(std::function<bool(Cache&)> cacheGetMethod, bool value)
    {
        m_getter = cacheGetMethod;
        m_value = value;
    }

    virtual bool check() const
    {
        // this is where I get the error, so the way I call the std::function object is wrong?
        return m_getter() == m_value;
    }

    virtual ~Condition() {}

private:
    std::function<bool(Cache&)> m_getter;
    bool m_value;
};
```

It is also a subclass of an abstract base class but I guess that this is not important for now.
Basically a Condition holds the function pointer to the getter of the Cache class to then get the latest value and compare it to a given value.

The Cache class looks like this:

```
class Cache
{
public:
    void setIsLampOn(bool isOn);
    bool getIsLampOn() const;

private:
    bool m_isLampOn;
};
```

And then here is how I use it in my main function:

```
std::shared_ptr<Cache> cache = std::make_shared<Cache>();

std::vector<ICondition*> conditions;
conditions.push_back(new Condition(std::bind(&Cache::getLamp, cache), true));
```

So the one Condition that I want to use basically checks wether the value of the lamp is true or not.

Comment: Here `std::function<bool(Cache&)>` you say the function takes a `Cache&`.  Why aren't you passing a `Cache` to it?

Comment: That is also, I'm pretty sure, not how to bind an instance to a member function anyway, since the implicit instance argument is a pointer (i.e. it is `this`). *Edit*: I take it back, as per my dupe suggestion: _"`std::bind()` is smart enough to use anything which looks like a pointer, anything convertible to a reference of the appropriate type (like `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`), or a [copy] of an object as the object when the first argument is a pointer to member."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How std::bind works with member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
std::function<bool(Cache&)> m_getter;
```

you say that the "function" object `m_getter` needs a reference to a `Cache` object as argument.

While it's correct that you need to pass a `Cache` object to the function you call (`setIsLampOn` or `getIsLampOn`) you set this object in your call to `std::bind`.

With your current `m_getter` you need to call it as `m_getter(SomeCacheObject)`.

You should not have `m_getter` need an argument:

```
std::function<bool()> m_getter;
```

Now you can call it as `m_getter()` and the `Cache` object you provided with `std::bind` will be used.