# How std::bind with std::placeholders to class member functions

Tags: c++

I have two class member functions to get bind. I have to pass placeholders, because the second class will set the arguments by themself.

Let's say I have a class

```
class slave
{
public:
   void func1();
   void func2(bool a, bool b);
};
```

and a second class

```
class master
{
public:
   std::function<void(void)> func1;
   std::function<void(bool, bool)> func2;
};
```

I can bound func1 und func2 like this

```
master Master;
slave Slave;

Master.func1 = std::bind(&slave::func1, &Slave);
Master.func2 = std::bind(&slave::func2, &Slave, true, false);
```

but how can I bind with placeholders?

without binding to a class member function I just can write:

```
std::function<void(bool, bool)> func2;
func2 = std::bind(&slave::func2, &Slave, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

but I can't write

```
Master.func2 = std::bind(&slave::func2, &Slave, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

How can I use placeholders for binding between class member functions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"but I can't write"`?  Please edit your question to include any error messages etc.

Comment: Why can't you write it? If an error is reported you  should include it *verbatim* in your post. [I cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/AAHDSc).

Comment: member functions have  implicit first argument(pointer to the instance of the class, aka this), so that could be your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions

Comment: I have a german Visual Studio v15: It tells: "Kein "=" -Operator stimmt mit diesem Operanden überein.

Sorry, I don't know what is the english bug report. Therefore I did not included it.

Comment: I know about the mentions question mentioned above. But it uses auto which can't be used in classes.

Comment: Don't use bind, use lambdas. `Master.func2 = [&](bool a, bool b){ Slave.func2(a, b); };`

Comment: Thanx, Lambda is working!

Comment: I recommend sticking to naming conventions: Class names start with upper case, instance names with lower case. You did it the other way around, which makes the code a bit harder to read. And while you're at it, maybe [drop the problematic terminology](https://www.theserverside.com/opinion/Master-slave-terminology-alternatives-you-can-use-right-now) as well.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your comment! I was never thinking about the second hint.

Comment: The error code ("Cxxxx" or "LNKxxxx") are not translated and they are very useful search keys online.

Comment: The error message means "no operator= matching ..." ... so the return value of that bind call seems to have a different type than `master.func2` ...