# Threadpool works with C code but fails to build in C++ project

Tags: c++

I am a beginner with threads and am trying to write code to extract 20 tags from a file.
The number of files can run up to 7000, so I would like to make good use of a thread-pool.

I use Code::Blocks 20.3 and MinGW 17.1 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

I have 'borrowed' the thread-pool code from: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221626/c17-thread-pool

I made a test that MinGW probably handles as C code, and that worked just fine.

My project involves multiple class files with dialog windows, and when I copied the working C code it fails to build. Unfortunately I do not understand how to convert the code from C to C++.

The test code I wrote is below.

The build messages are:

```
||=== Build: Debug in ThreadPool2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
Threadpool.h||In instantiation of 'auto Thread_Pool::execute(F, Args&& ...) [with F = TrackTags::TagsStdStrings (TrackTags::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>); Args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&}]':|
TrackTags.cpp|43|required from here|
Threadpool.h|62|error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<TrackTags::TagsStdStrings (TrackTags::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>'|
Threadpool.h|63|error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<TrackTags::TagsStdStrings (TrackTags::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>'|
Threadpool.h|62|error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<TrackTags::TagsStdStrings (TrackTags::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>'|
Threadpool.h|63|error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<TrackTags::TagsStdStrings (TrackTags::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>'|
TrackTags.cpp||In member function 'void TrackTags::GetMultiStdTags()':|
TrackTags.cpp|43|error: invalid use of void expression|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

the lines with errors are:

TrackTags.cpp

```
[43]  StdFutures.push_back(Pool.execute(GetStdTags, wsFile, wsCol));
```

Threadpool.h

```
[62]  std::packaged_task<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>()> Task_PKG(std::bind(function, args...) );
[63]  std::future<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>> Future = Task_PKG.get_future();
```

in Threadpool.h.

I tried:

```
[43] StdFutures.push_back(Pool.execute(std::mem_fn(TrackTags::GetStdTags), std::ref(wsFile), std::ref(wsCol)));
```

But this did not help.

I hope someone can help me make this work.
Thank you.

Ruud.

---TrackTags.h---

```
#ifndef TRACKTAGS_H
#define TRACKTAGS_H

#include "Threadpool.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class TrackTags
{
    public:
        struct TagsStdStrings
        {
            bool OK;
            std::string ThreadID;
            std::string FileName;
            std::string Collection;
        };

    public:
        TrackTags();
        virtual ~TrackTags();

        TagsStdStrings GetStdTags(std::string wsFile, std::string wsCollection);
        void GetMultiStdTags();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // TRACKTAGS_H
```

---TrackTags.cpp---

```
#include "TrackTags.h"

#define _UNICODE

TrackTags::TrackTags()
{
    //ctor
}

TrackTags::~TrackTags()
{
    //dtor
}

TrackTags::TagsStdStrings TrackTags::GetStdTags(std::string wsFile, std::string wsCollection)
{
    TagsStdStrings TagLine;
    TagLine.FileName = wsFile;
    TagLine.Collection = wsCollection;
    TagLine.OK = true;
    // Add thread-ID to the structure
    auto tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::stringstream ssID;
    ssID << tid;
    std::string sID{ssID.str()};
    TagLine.ThreadID = sID;
    return TagLine;
}

void TrackTags::GetMultiStdTags()

{
    Thread_Pool Pool(1);
    std::vector<std::future<TagsStdStrings>> StdFutures;
    std::string wsFile{"FileTest"};
    std::string wsCol{"ColTest"};
    StdFutures.push_back(Pool.execute(GetStdTags, wsFile, wsCol));
    for (auto &Fut : StdFutures)
    {
        TagsStdStrings TSS;
        TSS = Fut.get();
        if (TSS.OK)
        { std::cout << TSS.ThreadID << "--" << TSS.FileName << "--" << TSS.Collection << std::endl; }
        else
        { std::cout << "Empty Tag structure\n"; }
    }
}
```

---Threadpool.h---

```
#pragma once
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional> //bind
#include <future> //packaged_task
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits> //invoke_result
#include <vector>
class Thread_Pool
{
    public:
        Thread_Pool(size_t Thread_Count);
        ~Thread_Pool();
        Thread_Pool(const Thread_Pool &) = delete;
        Thread_Pool &operator=(const Thread_Pool &) = delete;
        template <typename F, typename ...Args>
        auto execute(F, Args&&...);
    private:
        class Task_Container_Base
        {
            public:
                virtual ~Task_Container_Base() {};
                virtual void operator()() = 0;
        };
        template <typename F>
        class Task_Container : public Task_Container_Base
        {
            public:
                Task_Container(F &&Fnc) : f(std::forward<F>(Fnc)) {}
                void operator()() override { f(); }
            private:
                F f;
        };
        template <typename Func>
        static std::unique_ptr<Task_Container_Base> Allocate_Task_Container(Func &&f)
        {
            return std::unique_ptr<Task_Container_Base>(new Task_Container<Func>(std::forward<Func>(f))
        );
    }
    std::vector<std::thread> Threads;
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Task_Container_Base>> Tasks;
    std::mutex Task_Mutex;
    std::condition_variable Task_CV;
    bool Stop_Threads = false;
};

template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto Thread_Pool::execute(F function, Args &&...args)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Queue_Lock(Task_Mutex, std::defer_lock);
    std::packaged_task<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>()> Task_PKG(std::bind(function, args...) );
    std::future<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>> Future = Task_PKG.get_future();
    Queue_Lock.lock();
    Tasks.emplace(Allocate_Task_Container( [Task(std::move(Task_PKG))]() mutable { Task(); }) );
    Queue_Lock.unlock();
    Task_CV.notify_one();
    return Future;
}
```

---Threadpool.cpp---

```
#include "Threadpool.h"
Thread_Pool::Thread_Pool(size_t Thread_Count)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Thread_Count; ++i)
    {
        Threads.emplace_back( std::thread( [&]()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Queue_Lock(Task_Mutex, std::defer_lock);
            while (true)
            {
                Queue_Lock.lock();
                Task_CV.wait( Queue_Lock, [&]() -> bool { return !Tasks.empty() || Stop_Threads; } );
                if (Stop_Threads && Tasks.empty()) return;
                auto Temp_Task = std::move(Tasks.front());
                Tasks.pop();
                Queue_Lock.unlock();
                (*Temp_Task)();
           }
       } ) );
    }
}

Thread_Pool::~Thread_Pool()
{
    Stop_Threads = true;
    Task_CV.notify_all();
    for (std::thread &Thread : Threads)
    {
        Thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you compile for C++17? Also note that there's no C code in the initial question on code review; that's also C++ code.

Comment: Yes I have configured both C and C++ test to C++17

Comment: I know that there is only c++17 code. Just do not see another explanation for it not to build.

Comment: I tried both C++17 ISO and C++17 ISO with GNU extensions.

Answer (score 0):

`GetStdTags` is a **non-static** member function.  You have access to `this` - the pointer to the object you're calling it on - inside it.  Therefore when you call it, you need to specify the object which the member function should be working on.

```cpp
Pool.execute(GetStdTags, wsFile, wsCol)
```

Here you only specify the two formal arguments, but not the object for the member function.  Passing that along would look like this:

```cpp
TrackTags one_object; // < yes, ONE, shared between the threads!
                      //   if you don't want to share it between threads,
                      //   you need to create multiple objects (and keep them alive)
Pool.execute(&TrackTags::GetStdTags, &one_object, wsFile, wsCol)
//           ^ pointer to member     ^ pointer
//             function                to object,
//                                     "this" inside the
//                                     member function
```

[More information about `std::bind` and member functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37636373/1116364)

However, *since* your class (`TrackTags`) doesn't have any data members and the member function `GetStdTags` doesn't need access to any object of type `TrackTags`, you can make it a **static** member function (or even a free function, really) and get by without a `TrackTags` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel.

The test project seemed to work, so I started on the "real" thing.

It is building without errors, but not working as planned.
I tested with 4 threads and 4 files and ran it twice.

Result below:  What did I miss?

```
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\01 Adam Baldych - Bridges.flac
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\02 Adam Baldych - Polesie.flac
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\03 Adam Baldych - Mosaic.flac
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\04 Adam Baldych - Riese.flac
6--Riese--Col Test
7--Riese--Col Test
8--Riese--Col Test
9--Riese--Col Test
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\01 Adam Baldych - Bridges.flac
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\02 Adam Baldych - Polesie.flac
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\03 Adam Baldych - Mosaic.flac
B:\Music\FLAC_Unlisted\Adam Baldych\Bridges\04 Adam Baldych - Riese.flac
```

First run, completes, but with wrong results, and the second run immediately after the first completed hangs.

This is the function called:

```
TrackTags::TagsStruct TrackTags::GetTags(wxString wsFile, wxString wsCollection)
{
    // create Tag variable structure
    struct TagsStruct TagLine;
    .
    .
    return TagLine
}
```

It loads a DLL and extracts the required tags from a file to return it in a structure with the Thread-ID as first item (temporary to check how the code runs).

The calling function is below:

```
void TrackTags::GetMultiStdTags()
{
    wxString wsCol{"Col Test"};
    std::vector<wxString> wsTracks
    {
        "B:\\Music\\FLAC_Unlisted\\Adam Baldych\\Bridges\\01 Adam Baldych - Bridges.flac",
        "B:\\Music\\FLAC_Unlisted\\Adam Baldych\\Bridges\\02 Adam Baldych - Polesie.flac",
        "B:\\Music\\FLAC_Unlisted\\Adam Baldych\\Bridges\\03 Adam Baldych - Mosaic.flac",
        "B:\\Music\\FLAC_Unlisted\\Adam Baldych\\Bridges\\04 Adam Baldych - Riese.flac"
    };

    TrackTags one_object;
    Thread_Pool Pool(4);
    std::vector<std::future<TagsStruct>> StdFutures;

    for (auto &tr : wsTracks)
    {
        std::cout << tr << std::endl;
        StdFutures.push_back(Pool.execute(&TrackTags::GetTags, &one_object, tr, wsCol));
    }


    for (auto &Fut : StdFutures)
    {
        TagsStruct TSS;
        TSS = Fut.get();
        if (TSS.OK)
        { std::cout << TSS.ThreadID << "--" << TSS.TrackTitle << "--" << TSS.Collection << std::endl; }
        else
        { std::cout << "Empty Tag structure found\n"; }
    }
}
```