# Cbfs driver document

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, windows-explorer

I have to create a Windows virtual drive using cbfs driver. I need to implement basic functionalities like delete, rename with some changes. Can someone please help me where can I get a document/ example to implement this using callbacks. I referred https://www.callbacktechnologies.com/kb/articles/1-GettingStartedWithCBFS.rst#File%20rename
, but it has only theory, I need examples. I am doing this in CPP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like you first need to download [CBFS Disk](https://www.callbacktechnologies.com/download/)
2. Then, follow their online documentation [here](https://www.callbacktechnologies.com/kb/help/).
3. SO has plenty of help using callback functions in C++. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c) for example. This [external site](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/) has a good callback tutorial as well.

Anyway you’ll need to install their library, integrate it with your code, use their API (available library methods, basically) to call their code...annnnd use callbacks if that’s what their API (or your assignment!) requires. Good luck.