# How to make a callback in C++: use a class member function as a parameter

Tags: c++, function, class, parameters

I started using C++ recently and at one point I needed to set up a callback, i.e. call a function of another class and pass to it as a parameter the name of one of my own functions so that it calls it back. At first I tried this:

```cpp
void myOtherFunction(void (*oneOfMyFunctions)(void)) {
    oneOfMyFunctions();
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't support class member functions because it is (correct me if I am wrong) ...C code.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c).

Comment: If it was C code it would probably work in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working way to do that:

```cpp
void myOtherFunction(std::function<void()> oneOfMyFunctions) {
    oneOfMyFunctions();
}
```

And inside my class:

```cpp
myOtherFunction([&] {
    oneOfMyFunctions();
});
```

Some explanations:
In `std::function<void()>`, void is what is returned by the function and () contains the types of its parameters (mine is empty because it doesn't have any).

In the 2nd code I am using a lambda to keep the context, as a bind would do (but lambdas replace them).

Comment: ??? Do you mean `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: std:: function doesn't exist in C

Comment: @JVApen OP seems to be writing C++. No member functions in C. They just assumed that their previous code was not working because it was C code.

Answer (score 1):

This can work.

```
void myOtherFunction(void (*oneOfMyFunctions)(void)) {
    oneOfMyFunctions();
}
```

However, your problem may be due to trying to pass member functions into this function. If `member_function` is a member function of class `A`, the expression `&member_function` inside class `A` has a type of `void (A::*)(void)`, not `void (*)(void)` like you want (that is, it wants an `A` pointer in addition to its normal parameters). You can use `std::bind()`:

```
std::bind(&member_function, this)
```

to create a function object which can be called with an empty parameter list. However, then you would need to change your member function signature to something like this:

```
template <typename FuncType>
void myOtherFunction(FuncType oneOfMyFunctions) {
    oneOfMyFunctions();
}
```

or, like Th0rgal may have said,

```
void myOtherFunction(std::function<void()> oneOfMyFunctions) {
    oneOfMyFunctions();
}
```