# Function callback in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, callback

I'm doing some C++ drills to learn the language.

Currently, I'm working on linear data structures, and I'm asked to implement sorting in a linked list without an extra array or structure.

Right now, I'd like to use callbacks in the `iterate()` function, to be flexible to call a `print()` function to check the values of a `findMin` to find the minimum value that will determine the base number for sorting.

I read this pretty useful guide about callbacks: [Callback functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/), but I can't reference the callback inside of my recursion call inside the `iterate()` function.

It would be nice to get some help to solve the issue that the comment in the code shows, but if you can let me know which concept I need to review/study, that would be even more helpful for building callback knowledge foundations.

```cpp
/* Implement sorting in a dynamic linked list without using an additional array or data structure.*/

#include <iostream>

class List{
  typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next = nullptr;
  }node;
  public:
    List(int data);
    ~List();
    void add(int data);
    void iterate(Node * node, void(*func)());
  private:
    int min = 0;
    Node* root;
    Node* it;
};

List::List(int data){
  root->data = data;
  it = root;
}

List::~List(){}


void List::iterate(Node * node, void(*func)()){
  func();//prints or finds min 
  if(node->next == nullptr)
    return;
  iterate(node->next,&func()); //--compiler says it can't get an address of a rvalue type void
}

int main(){
  List list(8); 
  list.add(9);
  list.add(7);
  list.add(4);
  list.add(3);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Omit the `()` in `&func()` — the parentheses convert the reference into a function call.  The `&` is unnecessary too, but mostly harmless.   That is, either `iterate(node->next, &func);` or `iterate(node->next, func);` should work.  Function pointers are slightly oddball.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonathanLeffler! It definitely worked on my side. Can I ask you for any recommended article/tutorial/material I can read to understand more about callbacks? I'd like to understand why your suggestion works

Comment: I commend the use of what I would I consider an idiomatic approach to a linked list in C++. One point, The C-style declaration of the node struct should be chaanged. `struct Node { /* members here */ };` is all you need.

Comment: If a variable `fp` has the type `pointer to function`, then using `fp(…)` (for an appropriate argument list, possibly an empty list) actually invokes the function, and the result is the return value (if any) from the function.  However, a function name without a following argument list becomes a 'pointer to function'.  You can also use `(fp)(…)` or `(*fp)(…)` to invoke the function.  The former version invokes the function by name, even if there is a macro override.  The second is the original notation used by pre-standard C.  Standard C allows `fp(…)` but pre-standard C required `(*fp)(…)`.

Comment: Is there a reason you use your own list instead of [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)? . Learning C++ is also about learning (re)use of tested library code. Side notes in C++ you can consider to use [std::function<void ()>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of function pointers, which will allow you to use [lambda functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (with captures) as parameter.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Writing a linked list from scratch is an **excellent** way to practice a lot of different principles at once. I wouldn't knock it.

Comment: @sweenish I agree, my comment wasn't about knocking anyone down.  My mode of thinking is more like if you want to test on callbacks only test that and use tested code for the rest.  ;)

Comment: Hey @sweenish! Thanks for your suggestion. Could you expand on it? I declared the structure in that way according to a book I'm reading but it would be great to read why you recommended `struct Node{ /*members here*/}`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler awesome, makes total sense now. So, adding the parenthesis makes the difference between calling it and a 'pointer to function' (it reminds of javascript callbacks). Thanks for that :)

Comment: The book you're reading is out-of-date. There is simply nothing to expand upon. You are using the C-style method, my suggestion is idiomatic C++.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I understand why you asked that, that's alright! When I learn something I always try to get good foundations even though doing that takes time. Recently, I finished a project on React.js that wouldn't have been so easy had I not had some practice (and headaches) working on a similar project with vanilla javascript. Certainly, I would use the standard library in a real work situation that's why I've planned to go into in detail in the future.

Comment: @sweenish gotcha, I'm gonna change that in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, in the following you are not passing the function pointer, but rather the address of the result of calling that function.

> ```
> void List::iterate(Node * node, void(*func)()){
>   func();//prints or finds min 
>   if(node->next == nullptr)
>     return;
>   iterate(node->next,&func()); //--compiler says it can't get an address of a > rvalue type void
> }
> ```

Rather:

```
void List::iterate(Node * node, void(*func)()) {
  func();
  if(node->next == nullptr)
    return;
  iterate(node->next, func); 
}
```