# Need some help with PVoid

Tags: c, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is pvoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494163/what-is-pvoid)

Hi,

Is PVoid is same as void* ? I want to know how to pass a pvoid to a function.

Say PVOID p;
  // In calling fn

```
callFn(&p);
```

//In calee

callfn(PVOID p)
  {
     //change p here

```
 *p= *s; or p = *s;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

looks like

```
callFn(PVOID p)
```

should be

```
callFn(PVOID *p)
```

which woul be the same as

```
callFn(void **p)
```

and callFn(&p) is passing the address of a pointer to the function callFn.

Answer (score 0):

`PVOID` is the same as `void *`. Unfortunately, a `void **` can be assigned to/passed as a `void *` without a cast. I think you may be running into this.